# C++ with STM32CubeMX and Eclipse System Workbench for STM32 AC6 tools

Tags: c++, eclipse, stm32, freertos

I generated a FreeRTOS project with `STM32CubeMX` for a Nucleo F429ZI demo board, built with success on `Eclipse System Workbench for STM32 AC6` tools and run on the demo board.
I would like to use `C++`, `stl` libraries.<
Simply renaming `main.c` to `main.cpp` does not work...
 I see someone was able to use C++ with FreeRTOS but I cannot find any help if with this STM32Toolchain it is possible.

Comment: renaming .c to .cpp does not migrate your project from C to C++. It is matter of compiler gcc/g++ and #inlcude headers and project configuration. also, check if you include the right STL lib headers.

Comment: What's the exact toolchain used? With gcc crosscompilers it shouldn't be a problem to use c++.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is posssible. And it's not so difficult (I assume you are using a standard ARM noneabi gcc). But you have to remember any futher modyfication in CubeMX will revert your project to C.

1. Rename your main.c to main.cpp (now, during compilation you should get an error `undefined reference to 'main'`.

---

2. Right Click on your STM project and select "Convert to C++". Now compilation is successful!

---

That's all. Remeber that you cannot invoke directly C++ functions form .c files. Also invoking interrupts by MCU will be also impossible when function is in .cpp file and doesn't have `extern "C"` attribute.
There is no matter if you include into project FreeRTOS, or any other stuff prepared by STM. C++ compiler works only with .cpp files and doesn't affect to .c files. So they works as earlier.

Comment: I started from a working C plain project with a blink. I added the C++
 nature `<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature</nature>`, renamed `main.c` to `main.cpp`, added all include settings and build successfully. But when debug the program does not start and shows `STM32F429ZITx.cpu: target state: halted`

Comment: Now i'am not able to check this (i haven't access to any board at the moment) but i do not remeber any problems with debuging after this change (in my way - i'm not sure if your solution is the same). Remember to check version of your debbugger and compiler and, if neccessary, update them.

Comment: The toolchain is `Ac6 STM32 MCU GCC`. The debugger starts, here is last console output: `xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08008d08 msp: 0x20030000` but the program does not run. It looks like it does not find the `main()` entry point, even using `extern "C"`

Comment: If you can, try do some debugging on startup_stm32f429xx.s file. Sometimes line 109: `bl __libc_init_array` causes hardfaults. I always remove this line by comment and never find any problems with this. 

This probles occoures because of the implematiation of standard library and assosiated with linker flags: `-specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs`. At this moment i can't remember which parameter. I didn't work with this for long time.

Answer (score 1):

I [used](http://www.openstm32.org/forumthread2509?topics_offset=8) the Eclipse `Convert to C++` menu instead of the `New -> Convert to a C/C++ project (Adds C/C++ Nature)` menu.
 This command copied correctly all project settings. Then I renamed the `main.c` to `main.cpp`, compiled and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I did it for Keil IDE.  you should generate an STM32 MDK project normally by STM32CubeMX with  updated HAL drivers
then open project in Keil ARM MDK, change project-option-C/C++ -MiscControls to --cpp
and for the last step, you should create user C++ files in .hpp and .cpp